# EF: configuring many to many relationship (code first)

Tags: entity-framework

In my scenario I have Jobs, Companies and Departments.

Single Job may have only one Company; Company may have multiple Jobs (One-To-Many)

Single Job may have multiple Departments; Department may have multiple Jobs (Many-To-Many).

I want to set relations using Foreign Keys only. For that I have property of Foreign Key and lazy navigation property.

These are my classes:

```
public class JobEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Companies CompanyId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    //Navigation
    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public virtual CompanyEntity Company
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public IList<Departments> Departments
    {
        get;
        set;
    }       

    //navigation
    public virtual IList<DepartmentEntity> DepartmentsNavigation
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public class DepartmentEntity
{
    public Departments Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    //navigation
    public virtual IList<JobEntity> Jobs
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public class CompanyEntity
{
    public Companies Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    //navigation
    public virtual List<JobEntity> Jobs
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Also, I have many-to-many mapping inside my context:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<JobEntity>()
                    .HasMany<DepartmentEntity>(s => s.DepartmentsNavigation)
                    .WithMany(c => c.JobsNavigation)
                    .Map(cs =>
                    {
                        cs.MapLeftKey("JobId");
                        cs.MapRightKey("DepartmentId");
                        cs.ToTable("JobsDepartments");
                    });

    }
```

When I set CompanyId into Job, everything work as expected: when I getting Job from DB, I have an associated Company lazy loaded.

However, when I setting into Job list of related foreign keys ('Departments') - when I loading Job from DB this list is null and departments navigation property ('DepartmentsNavigation') having count of 0 (I was expected to have collection of department ids that I set + lazy loaded collection of departments).

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For many-to-many, you can't use a foreign key association.

There's a reference to this [here](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/05/foreign-key-vs-independent-associations-in-ef-4/):

> One-to-one relation in EFv4 always uses Foreign Key association and many-to-many relation always uses Independent association.

and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713299.aspx):

> **Note**: In many-to-many (*:*) you cannot add foreign keys to the entities. In a *:* relationship, the association information is managed with an independent object.

and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564):

> However, if you have a pure many-to-many relationship that is connected by a join table that contains only foreign keys, the EF will use an independent association to manage such many-to-many relationship.

Your foreign keys are already in the `JobsDepartments` table, so EF won't let you add additional foreign keys for that relationship in the `JobEntity` and `DepartmentEntity` entities.